# how to create dynamic menu in extjs3?

Tags: extjs, menu, toolbar, extjs3, tbar

I have Ex. 10 menu in menu header and each of this has permission base so if user have permission for particular menu then that menu will be show for that user only in menu header.

If particular user have all menu(ex...10) permission so in that case application menu header part have not sufficient width so i want like after 5 menu, more menu/button kind of thing show and 6-10 menus are appearing in that more menu/button.

After I Appling all 10 menu permission to particular user, then when I remove 1 menu permission from 1 to 5 at that time 6th menu come out from the more menu and display in menu header and if I again give permission for that remove menu then 6th menu remove from the header and put it into more menu/button.

Comment: can you please provide more details? code or even better sencha fiddle representing your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the 6-10 menu to overflow to to a menu:

just set `enableOverflow:true` on the toolbar the menus (or splitbuttons) are located in... this works for any amount of toolbar items, not just menus

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a3t